# PHP: line charts

Tags: php, charts, graph

I can manage to build a line chart like in pic 1, but would like to know how to build one like in pic 2. I need the graph to be filled with color (like in pic 2). How would I do that?

[image]

Comment: @Alen : I've edited this question, to add the link to the picture that you posted in a duplicate -- if needed, you can edit your questions, instead of re-ask them with more information *(your other question, which is the same as this one, will likely get closed as a duplicate)*

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you're using, but [the excellent pChart library](http://pchart.sourceforge.net/) can do this:

[image: Graph]

Comment: On the pChart website it says that to run it on a server you need to use PHP compiled with GD library support. How common is this (eg. if you don't run your own server)? Also, if they don't already support it how easy is it to update the PHP to one with GD support?

Comment: GD library is very common. I have not seen a web host without GD compiled.

Answer (score 0):

The second pic seems to be drawn pixel by pixel with [setpixel](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagesetpixel.php) function (in case of [GD extension](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php)). All you need is to fill the lower pixels with a color after drawing the one representing value.

If you would like to make a similar graph as on pic1 but filled with a color you can use [imagefilledpolygon](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilledpolygon.php) function to draw the graph.

Answer (score 0):

We generally use a [commercial component](http://www.amcharts.com) for graphs. It uses flash but as great functionnalities and customization capabilities.

If you want some jpeg or gif picture graphs, in the far past we used to work with [jpgraph](http://www.aditus.nu/jpgraph/) which is now PHP5 and Object oriented.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check out:

**http://jpgraph.net/**
*(Little heavy, but has lot of features)*
Example of what you need: http://jpgraph.net/features/src/show-example.php?target=new_line5.php